# All my controls vanished after editing assembly

Tags: vb.net

So I edited the assembly information, got ton of errors such as "not able to load file/assembly", managed to get them away somehow, restart VS to find all my controls gone.

In my "MainFrm.Designer.vb" I can see the controls like this:

```
Friend WithEvents ConfigList As OSLOK1NGS.LogInTitledListBox
Friend WithEvents TabPage2 As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
Friend WithEvents TabPage3 As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
Friend WithEvents TabPage4 As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
```

However they're not initialized like this:

```
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(849, 476)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.LogInThemeContainer2)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.Name = "MainFrm"
    Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Me.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Fuchsia
    Me.LogInThemeContainer2.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.LogInTabControl2.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
```

Please don't say they're gone, too many hours of work was put into this.

Comment: ***They are gone*** I am afraid you wiped out the `.designer` files that stores this information. I hope you have `GIT` or `TFS` or some sort of backup/version control... `managed to get them away somehow` what way was that, that might have done it...

Comment: Well it is an assembly... anything can go wrong. What did you change, if you went through the designer to make these changes, I couldn't see how this would happen...

Comment: One would have thought changing the trademark and copyright 3 chars via the GUI would be safe but no.

Comment: No, that would definitely not cause that if you did it through the GUI... I've changed this stuff many times before and never experience such problems. I believe something else was changed...